# emacs powershell versus powershell-mode

Tags: powershell, emacs

I would like to use PowerShell inside my emacs, and I am interested in my options. Trying `M-x package-install RET powershell TAB` shows two options: `powershell` and `powershell-mode`. How do these packages compare? How do they compare to `powershell.el`?

The following resources were very helpful, but they do not answer my question:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PowerShell

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/04/10/run-powershell-as-a-shell-within-emacs.aspx

[Can I use PowerShell in shell-mode for Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872510/can-i-use-powershell-in-shell-mode-for-emacs)

I am on Emacs 24.3 with Windows 7.

Comment: just wanted to note my annoyance at moderators that criticize perfectly valid questions. This type of activity is what creates the ugly atmosphere here and forces people to look for other places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, both of these are incomplete in some aspects, and both are apparently unmaintained.

Instead, use [powershell.el](https://github.com/jschaf/powershell.el).  It is on MELPA, available for installation with `M-x package-install RET powershell`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but when I run `M-x package-install-file`, and enter the location `~/.emacs.d/elisp/powershell.el`, I get `;;; powershell-mode.el ends here`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Lucas I see.  There are [some issues in the current version](https://github.com/jschaf/powershell.el/pull/2).  Apply the patch in the link locally to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the default shell (via M-x shell) and then type "powershell" at the command prompt. You're now running PowerShell inside cmd.exe inside EMACS. #workaround

Is there anything specific you want to use PowerShell for that you can't do in eshell?