# Running Clojure Box in Windows 7

Tags: ide, clojure

Has anyone had a problem running Clojure Box in Windows 7?

I am trying to run a fresh install of Clojure Box on a fresh install of Windows 7 Professional (64 bit). Java version on system is 1.6.0_16.

emacs starts up but produces the following error messages:

```
    Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `~/.emacs':

    File error: Searching for program, no such file or directory, java
```

As a newbie at emacs, slime, swank, paredit, Clojure and Clojure Box, I'm not even sure where to start. I can't even *find* `~/.emacs'

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the directory you installed Java to on your PATH?

Comment: No. Thanks for a civil answer to a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error by not having Java installed at all prior to installing Clojure Box. It'd be nice if the installer checked for Java's presence and PATH-belonging. Once [Java was installed](http://www.java.com/en/download/), Clojure Box was working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alex. Yup, one more thing to check for. In addition to checking for these things on my own when I install new programs, they are things I can add to the installers I build for the programs I write too.

Answer (score 1):

You may create .emacs file yourself. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows/189509#189509) answer.

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha is that there is a emulation of the 32 bit process on the 64 bit version of Windows so you need to add java files to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 even if you have it in C:\Windows\System32 folder.