# Where is the .emacs file in windows GNU emacs

Tags: emacs, winapi, path

Where is the .emacs file in windows (I'm using Emacs-23-CvsP091103-EmacsW32-1.58 )

> When Emacs starts up, it attempts to
>   load and execute the contents of a
>   file commonly called .emacs (though it
>   may have other names, see Where do I
>   put my init file?) which contains any
>   customizations you have made. You can
>   manually add lisp code to your .emacs,
>   or you can use the Customization
>   interface accessible from the Options
>   menu. If the file does not exist,
>   Emacs will start with the default
>   settings.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your home directory. You can set this directory by setting the `HOME` environment variable. If home isn't set, it will look in your Application Data directory. On XP, that's something like `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data`, on Vista and later `C:\Users\<username>\AppData`.

If you open up emacs, and try editing (with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>) `~/.emacs`, that should generally open up the `.emacs` that Emacs will be loading.

See the [Windows Emacs FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Installing-Emacs.html#index-HOME-directory-48) for more details.

To set the `HOME` environment variable, open the System Control Panel, go to the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables, then click the New button in the "User variables" section.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out where `.emacs` resides by default on a particular system is without a doubt <kbd>C-h v user-emacs-directory</kbd>. The `user-emacs-directory` variable is platform dependent and is helpful on each and every OS.

Answer (score 0):

My version of emacs on windows (22.3.1) places the init file there:
~/.emacs/init.el

(see Brian Campbell's post for the definition of ~, which is HOME).

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to a file (e.g. c:/.emacs).

```
;; This function must be at begin
(defun zxy-relocate-dotemacs ()
  "Relocate .emacs file"
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let (print-level print-length)
      (insert (format "(load-file \"%s\")" load-file-name))
      (if (file-exists-p "~/.emacs")
          (message "[zxy] Don't need relocate .emacs file!")
        (progn
          (message "[zxy] Relocate .emacs file.")
          (write-file "~/.emacs"))))))
(zxy-relocate-dotemacs)
;; Your configuration here
```

Open emacs and M-x load-file c:/.emacs.

Then it will relocate .emacs to c:/.emacs.

I use this when I copy my emacs to a new computer.

More information please visit my blog abuot emacs.
http://coordinate.sinaapp.com/?cat=3