# Where to put .emacs file in Carbon Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, development-environment, carbon-emacs

I'm new to Emacs if you can't tell. Right now I am using Carbon Emacs on Mac OSX. I would like to customize the layout and whatnot but I have no idea where I can find or make a new .emacs file in order to do so.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the .emacs file in windows GNU emacs ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966380/where-is-the-emacs-file-in-windows-gnu-emacs)

Comment: @Trey Carbon emacs is one of the several Mac OS versions. Do you *really* think that this is a duplicate of a Windows specific questions?

Comment: @dmckee Do you *really* think that Emacs isn't cross platform?  Emacs looks for the .emacs file in the same locations on all platforms, one of which is relative to the `HOME` environment variable, which is exactly what you wrote, which is what the duplicate answer says...

Comment: @Trey: I know that Mac OS Classic didn't have the concept of a home directory (so that each port had to solve this problem, by using the Preferences folder for instance) and that the Windows answer had to deal with the special meaning of '.' in that context. If "Where does .emacs go on OS?" is valid at all then Windows and Mac OS are different.

Comment: @dmckee Did you read the accepted answer for that question?  It has the general solution...  i.e. `C-x C-f ~/.emacs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put mine in my home directory (i.e. the usual place for unix installations of emacs) and it works fine:

```
$ ls -lh /Users/dmckee/.emacs
-rw-r--r-- 1 dmckee staff 11K Aug  4 09:28 /Users/dmckee/.emacs
```

Comment: That's what I thought I was supposed to do. But none of the styling appears. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Hunter: I think you're going to have to be more specific about what you're done and what you are/are not seeing...

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

In the scratch buffer, evaluate the following...
(find-file user-init-file)