# Pymacs error starting Emacs after installing Python

Tags: python, emacs, pymacs

I installed python using one of the msi files. But when I start up emacs, it gives me:

**Problem 1, which I thought I'd fixed**

When I run cmd and type in python, I get

```
"python" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So from online sources, (windows 7 btw) Went to System Properties and Environmental Variables and added a User variable for my specific user

> Path and %PATH%;C:\Python27

It worked for a bit, not its not.

**Problem 2:**

> pymacs-report-error: Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds

and I have no idea why. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked that pymacs works as they say to do so in the documentation ? : http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html#check-if-pymacs-would-work

Comment: Can you give us an installation sequence? Also, which version of Pymacs are you using? I've had this problem before and I fixed it myself. But first I need to know if we have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your executable must be "python" instead of "python2.7" (for example).

In addition, Pymacs must be installed into the site-packages directory (or a directory in your PYTHONPATH env variable) of your python directory (on UNIX based systems, I use 'pip' or 'easy_install').

Finally, pymacs.el must be placed in your ~/.emacs.d/vendor/ (for example) directory (on windows, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows)) and correctly loaded.

In my ~/.emacs.d/init.el I have this :

```
(setq my-dot-emacs-dir "~/.emacs.d")
(setq my-vendor-emacs-dir (concat my-dot-emacs-dir "/vendor"))
(add-to-list 'load-path my-vendor-emacs-dir)
```

You can adapt this code to load automatically .el files situated in your .emacs.d/vendor/

Comment: for me (ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04) the problem was caused by pymacs being installed in dist-packages - this seems to be a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/852287). I tried to install by pip but this didn't seem to build the python library properly. In the end I did this `cp cp -r /usr/share/pyshared/Pymacs /my/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`