# Where is my emacs configuration file on Win7?

Tags: python, emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find my .emacs file for Emacs running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows)

I am a total newbie to emacs.

I know I can edit a configuration file to change the behavior of my emacs editor and customize it for python editing. but I can't seem to find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a duplicate, and dependent on how emacs was installed. Cygwin will mimic a *nix setup, handling your usage dot-files in your `C:\Users\<Username>` directory or in `C:\cygwin\home\<username>` depending on how you configured your installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on windows XP. But inside emacs i can open it using:

```
 C-x C-f  ~/.emacs
```

or

```
 C-x C-f  ~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

You then can also see to what `~` autocompletes to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think GNU Emacs puts it in the Documents folder '_emacs'. I'm not at a Win 7 box right now to double check.