# Emacs init.el file doesn't load

Tags: emacs, init

When I open emacs, the following messages appear in the `*Messages*` buffer, and my init.el file (located at `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) doesn't load.

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cedet-common.el (source)...
Error while loading 50cedet-common: Cannot open load file: cedet-autogen
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50haskell-mode.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/haskell-mode/haskell-site-file.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50haskell-mode.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50php-elisp.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/51speedbar.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
```

I can't find any helpful information about cedet when I google it or look on the emacs wiki. Oddly, when I use `M-x eval-buffer` or `M-x load-file`, everything works fine. `HOME` is what it should be, and I'm running version `23.3.1`.

I had been trying to get jshint working with emacs before this happened, though I'm not sure if that's at all relevant https://github.com/daleharvey/jshint-mode.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Remove the `~/.emacs` file first. See [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it immediately.