# Setting up Emacs to run Scheme code

Tags: emacs, scheme

I have emacs 24.5 for windows installed, and when I try to run a scheme program in the buffer with C-x C-e it says `run-scheme` and when I hit enter it then says `searching for program: no such file or directory, scheme`. Looking around I have only found tutorials for unix systems, and downloading Linux is not an option for me at this computer. The other resources I have found were vague or unhelpful. I would really like to use emacs but so far I have not been able to use it at all

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about scheme, but it is probably safe to say that Emacs can't find the binary executable of `scheme` on your hard drive.  For example, it might be located at `c:\hello_world\scheme.exe`.  In general, Emacs uses a variable to set the location of an executable and it often tries something like `executable-find` -- if the `scheme.exe` is not in the PATH used by Emacs, then add its folder location to the PATH or modify the variable that points to executable to use the absolute path to `scheme.exe`.  If you haven't installed `scheme.exe` yet, then install it.

Comment: It should be using xscheme.el which is inside the emacs directory, it comes with the install

Comment: For example, you may wish to configure the variable `scheme-program-name` to use the absolute path -- e.g., `(setq scheme-program-name "c:\hello_world\scheme.exe")`  The variable is defined in the library `scheme.el` which is required by the library cited by Jordan in the comment above.  The default value is `scheme` which will only work if the folder where `scheme.exe` is located is on the PATH used by Emacs -- using the absolute path will likely resolve the issue.  Be sure to evaluate the expression or restart Emacs after adding the above code-snippet to the `.emacs` file.

Comment: Where is the .emacs file located at in reference to the parent emacs directory?  Is the file just ".emacs" or "textleftout.emacs"? I imagine if I was able to set this up in a Unix environment it would be considerably simpler, but using unix tools on windows is definitely difficult.

Comment: You will need to create the `.emacs` file -- a plain flat text file and place it in your home directory.  Here are a few links that describe where it is located on Windows:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows  For example, I use Windows XP and I chose to create an `init.el` file inside my `.emacs.d` directory, which is an alternative to using a `.emacs` file.  For me:  `c:/Documents and Settings/lawlist/Application Data/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: @Jordan, `xscheme.el` is not an implementation of Scheme; it [interacts with a separately-installed MIT Scheme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExScheme). So you'll have to make sure to have MIT Scheme installed as well, and ensure that Emacs / `xscheme.el` can find it as suggested by others. (Note that other Schemes won't work with `xscheme.el`, as mentioned in the previous link.)

Answer (score 2):

1. M-x customize-variable
2. Enter 'scheme-program-name'. Press Enter.
3. Replace 'scheme' with the path to your Scheme executable.
4. Click the 'State' button and select 'Save for Future Sessions'.

Or, you could add the path to your Scheme to Windows' PATH variable and only use its name in 'scheme-program-name'.

Or, you can edit your startup file by hand, but that's not really necessary.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work, I put in C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe and it still says "searching for program: no such file or directory, scheme :/

Comment: Is there something other than mit-scheme I could use with this