# How to install go-mode in Emacs on windows?

Tags: emacs

**MELPA** is unix based. 
I've been trying to install go-mode in *emacs* but came to nothing.

Are there any ways to install go-mode with all of its features in *emacs* on Windows

Answer (score 0):

add this to your init file:

```
(package-install 'go-mode)
```

or just paste it into the scratch buffer and `M-X eval-last-sexp`

Comment: Were does init file supposed to be located on windows? Where should i put it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows