# Porting OS X Emacs setup to Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, emacs, porting

I need to port an existing Mac emacs setup to Windows. I downloaded the Windows emacs zip archive from here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#windows. On my Mac, I have the package downloaded from here: https://emacsformacosx.com/

On my Mac, I have my entire `~/.emacs.d` under version control. I've done quite a bit of work configuring packages, key bindings, etc. Most of my custom config is at the end of `init.el`.

On my windows, the initial folder for my emacs (`c/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/`) has the following things (I found the folder via [Where can I find my .emacs file for Emacs running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows)):

1) a `.emacs.d` folder, which contains a single folder called    `auto-save-list` containing non-config-related things

2) a `#.emacs#` file

3) a `.emacs` file

4) a `.emacs~` file

I'm not sure of the differences between the 3 variations of the .emacs file in my Windows folder, but editing `~/.emacs` from INSIDE emacs seems to edit both the `.emacs` and `.emacs~` files, and changing a keybinding there does seem to reflect in Emacs itself.

However, directly copying the version-controlled `.emacs.d` folder from my Mac into the `.emacs.d` folder on Windows does nothing.

Surely emacs on Windows doesn't load everything from just a single file?

What's the relationship between all the `.emacs` things in my Windows folder, and what's the best way to port my config?

Comment: `.emacs` (other files are just editor savings)

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I port my entire .emacs.d folder from my mac into a single file. Or are you suggesting I just concat all the lines?

Comment: `C-h v user-emacs-directory` should tell you where Emacs is looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the way to have Emacs read from the `.emacs.d` folder is to first manually delete all the `.emacs` files in the top-level folder (for me, thelrner/AppData/Roaming). This will force Emacs to seek out the `init.el` inside thelrner/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d, just like in OS X.

Docs here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD