# Move Emacs from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, emacs

I've had a break from programming the last two years and want to start up again. Right now I'm using a Windows computer, but my work and compiler is on my Linux computer.

My question is:

Is it possible to move my entire emacs work environment from Ubuntu to Windows 10? I did some changes in emacs back in the days that I got used to and would love to continue like that on my Windows computer.

Comment: All of your elisp will work (assuming you use compatible versions of Emacs between the two systems). You give no information regarding any other aspects of your "entire emacs work environment", so it's hard to say anything more than that.

Comment: @phils Thank you for your reply! Sorry for the little info I gave. My experience with Emacs is slim and it is 2 years ago, so I don't really know what Emacs I use other than the standard emacs I downloaded from the site. The lisp code was all I changed if I recall right.


How can I know if the version is compatible between the systems? And where do I move the elisp file from and to where?

Comment: This should be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly...

The most important things to copy are your `~/.emacs.d` directory and your init file (see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Init File` for the different filenames this might have, or check with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `user-init-file`).

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Windows HOME` regarding where the `.emacs.d` directory should live on your Windows system.

Note the comments in that Info node on the `site-lisp` directory as well, in case you've been using elisp libraries in there (possibly without realising), as they can form part of your Emacs configuration as well.

Any byte-compiled elisp (`.elc` files) should remain compatible so long as you're moving to an equal-or-newer version of Emacs (which sounds likely in this case).  Natuarally things do change between releases, though, and it's possible to encounter incompatibilities when upgrading, but I wouldn't worry about that in advance -- try the latest version first, and if you run into problems that you can't solve (which shouldn't be very likely), you can always install the version of Emacs you were originally using.

Comment: Thanks alot, appreciate your time. Good day :)