# Find .emacs file on Windows bash

Tags: emacs, configuration, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to change few things in my .emacs configuration file. The problem is that I cannot find it.

Does anyone have any idea where it could be on Windows bash?

Is it even called .emacs on windows Bash? Do I have to create it myself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows?rq=1), which suggest various ways to find the `.emacs` configuration file through Emacs itself. Not sure how you'd find it using only Bash, though - I imagine Bash and Emacs could have different ideas of where the "home directory" is.

Comment: @legoscia, thanks for your link. For some reasons, I think the `.emacs` file does not exist on my windows bash. In fact, I found the `.emacs.d` folder, but it only contains save files. I find it kind of strange to need to create it myself. I have not tried it yet though.

Comment: @souki:  The .emacs file is for your personal customizations; if you have not had occasion to change Emacs' default behaviour, there is no reason it should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, here is what I understood :

As Varro said in the commnent, `.emacs` file will not be created by default, since it will only contain cuztomizations you want. So you have to create it yourself. By the way, apparently it is a good practice to call it `init.el`. To find where to create it, type `env` in the terminal and look for the `HOME` variable. This value will show you the path considered as the home directory, where emacs created `.emacs.d/` folder. You must create `init.el` file in this folder, and emacs will load it automatically.

This is not related to the question but it might help you :

I needed this file in order to change the cursor on emacs. At first, I thought that emacs was not loading the file correctly, because the cursor was not changing. I made some tests, and I was able to change background color, so it was not the problem. But, in fact, you can NOT change the cursor, since it is defined by the terminal itself, not emacs.